# Can't create a SubMenu

Tags: menus

I have created a new WordPress blog at http://www.shanytopper.com and I have a problem.

I am using a `wp_nav_menu` for the main menu in my website (I added the suppert to the theme myself), and it works great, but when I'm at the admin page and trying to make a submenu (some catagories need to be under some other ones) it doesn't seem to work.

Specificaly, it doesn't allow me to drag the menu item "sideways", and thus create the second tier. It only allow me to change the order the items show on the menu but on the same tier.

Anyone have any idea on what my cause this?

I have tried using a different Theme (that already has Menus support), and yet the problem remains, so I'm doubtfull it's something I did.

Answer (score 2):

Found out the problem was a plugin called [TPC! Memory Usage](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tpc-memory-usage/). Not sure on why, but turning it off fixed it, so you know, whatever.